# Merging lists of different types into List<Any>, but keeping their property

Tags: android, kotlin

I only started learning Kotlin and I'm not a strong programmer anyway :) So I have this data class to parse a JSON with that looks like this:

```
data class DataClass(
    val crazy: List<Crazy>,
    val hardcore: List<Hardcore>,
    val jackpot: List<Jackpot>,
    val kinky: List<Kinky>,
    val light: List<Light>
)

data class Crazy(
    val text: String
)

...blah blah rest of data classes that have the same text property

data class Light(
    val text: String
)
```

I need to merge them all in a single var, so I created a list of type Any.

```
    challengesObject = gson.fromJson(fileStream, DataClass::class.java)

var allChallenges: List<Any> = challengesObject.light + challengesObject.crazy + challengesObject.hardcore + challengesObject.kinky
```

All good so far, it works, but obviously I can't access the text var because they lost their type. How could I go about implementing a solution to merge them into one list and still keep access to the text var?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. You could add an "interface HasText { val text: String }" and make all your `data class`es implement that. The combined list can then be a `List<HasText>`

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: If every model have same text variable, then why don't you use same model for all the list?